bluetooth speaker oscillates repeatedly between being detected as handsfree and speaker
I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04 from 22.04. This problem was not happening in Ubuntu 22.04 I connect my Bluetooth speaker (JBL Charge 3), to the laptop (Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 Pro) and it connects successfully.
However it periodically switches between being detected as a handsfree for about 2 seconds to speaker for about 2 seconds, back and forth indefinitely.
The issue was briefly fixed for an entire day shortly after installing ubuntu-restricted-extras, however it has come back and I am unable to resolve it.
I have tried reinstalling pulseaudio and alsa-base but that has not worked.
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions!
